# How to open a page with react-router-dom without any event?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-router-dom

I want to open homepage only if login data is correct i.e. getting success in response

```
<form>
//inputs
<button type="submit" onClick={(e) => sendData(e)}> Sign-In </button>
</form>
```

```
 const sendData = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    axios({ method: "POST", url: url, data: data, headers: header })
      .then((res) => {
        if (res.data.status === "success") {

          props.sethistory(res.data.data.user.history);//getting data from response
          props.setsignedIn(true);  

          //what to do here to open homepage
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  };
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "open homepage"? Do you mean, navigate to the homepage, whatever path that may be? What have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this will surely help you,

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
const history = useHistory();
```

then use it programatically, when your login is `success`, put this code, will take you to that URL component home for example in your case

```
history.push("/YOURURL");
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on which version of `react-router-dom` you are using the process is basically the same: issue an imperative navigation action.

### Version 5

In versions 5 this is accomplished via the `history` ***object***, accessed via injected [route props](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-props) (`history`, `location`, and `match`) or with React hooks (`useHistory`, `useLocation`, `useParams`).

Example:

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

...

// in function body "unpack" history object
const history = useHistory();

...

const sendData = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  axios({ method: "POST", url: url, data: data, headers: header })
    .then((res) => {
      if (res.data.status === "success") {
        props.sethistory(res.data.data.user.history);
        props.setsignedIn(true);  

        history.push("/homepage"); // <-- imperative navigation
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
};
```

[useHistory](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/usehistory)

### Version 6.x

In version 6 the API was significantly updated, and route props no longer exist and the same "values" are accessible via React hooks. The `history` object is also no longer directly exposed, but rather you are given a `navigate` ***function*** to invoke with the target path.

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

...

// in function body "unpack" navigate function
const navigate = useNavigate();

...

const sendData = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  axios({ method: "POST", url: url, data: data, headers: header })
    .then((res) => {
      if (res.data.status === "success") {
        props.sethistory(res.data.data.user.history);
        props.setsignedIn(true);  

        navigate("/homepage"); // <-- imperative navigation
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
};
```

[useNavigate](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#usenavigate)